# Get video encoding type or mime type before playing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm developing a video player in as3. It will need to easily switch between mp4 and flv files. This is easy if you do:

`netStream.play(encoding + ":" + videoSrc);`

The problem is getting the value for `encoding`. I don't want to rely on the extension to detect this, since there might not be one. I thought I could make a HEAD request on the file and read the content-type header, but I can't seem to do this with `URLRequest` and `URLRequestHeader` since they only support POST and GET. How can I detect the  encoding without some kind of prior knowledge?